# Increase frame rate of CreateJS's TweenJS for use w/ three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, createjs, tween

I'm using CreateJS's [TweenJS](http://createjs.com/tweenjs) in a 60fps three.js project. I'm noticing the animation feels jerky when I use TweenJS to move objects, as if the objects are being updated at a lower frame rate.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sccottt/sbm9s6k5/1/

In the example, the box (animated w/ TweenJS) seems to move much less smoothly than the lines in the background (rotating per `requestAnimationFrame()`).

Is there a way to change the frame rate of TweenJS, or does anyone have any idea on how to make this perform more smoothly?

Comment: can you build this with three's stats plugin, or something to show the frame rate? Bot yours and the demo from the answer still seem sluggish compared to the ribbons. I dont know much about cratejs but i took a look at the ticker class. Ideally you want to update the tween everytime you render - in your render loop. I suspect that your frame rate is 60, but tween and three are out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of CreateJS that JSFiddle will host is fairly old (end of 2013). Since then, there is RequestAnimationFrame support <strike>(now used as the default timing mode)</strike>.

I updated your fiddle, to use the latest (0.6.1, tagged on May 21) with RAF, and it seems much smoother.
https://jsfiddle.net/sbm9s6k5/4/

```
createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
```

Comment: For compatibility with existing content, Ticker still uses TIMER (ie. setTimeout) as the default timingMode. Otherwise Lanny's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note the `tweenjs.min.js` library that you include in your fiddle is not actually being used as you might think. Instead the `createjs` version is being used.

Anyway I went with the original tween.js which is under three.js/examples/libs/tween.min.js and did a rewrite of your tween code and I believe the result is much smoother.

```
setInterval( function()
{
    var trgt    = randomV3();

    new TWEEN.Tween( _someone.position )
        .to( { x: trgt.x, y: trgt.y, z: trgt.z }, 2000 )
        .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut )
        .onUpdate( function() {
            _someone.position.set( this.x, this.y, this.z );
        } )
        .start()
    ;
}, 2250 );
```

**fiddle** at https://jsfiddle.net/2v4tqaux/

Comment: steel seems sluggish compared to the rotating ribbons, i think it's a matter of calling TWEEN.update() at an appropriate time, but i dont know much about createjs

Comment: Create.js does not have a tween.update method. All is encapsulated in that one call you are using. Anyway, you are trying to compare simple rotation, I.e. Matrix multiply, with interpolation. Apples and oranges I would say.

Comment: @gaitat – I do definitely notice a difference. I was hoping to use the `createjs` version as I'm already using it a bunch in the project and I like the syntax better, but it looks like tween.js works.

Comment: all im saying is that in each render tick, you should have your positions and rotations updated. Are you saying that the comparison of rotation and interpolation is causing this difference? I'm saying, if this is designed correctly, if anything heavy hit the cpu, the whole frame would lag. This is a very simple issue. You need to update your tween, at the same time you update all your 3d stuff, then render. These two are out of sync. If create.js does not have this or a similar method, don't use create.js.